# Union multiple Delete Queries or otherwise combine

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I have 3 separate delete queries that I would like to either : Union together so they can be run in one click or re-write so that I can perform all the actions in a single query. I have so far been unable to do so. The queries are as follows:

Delete Duplicate Leads

```
DELETE WorkBook.*, Exists (select 1 
       from Leads 
WHERE WorkBook.Email=Leads.Email) AS Expr1
FROM WorkBook
WHERE (Exists (select 1 
       from Leads
WHERE WorkBook.Email=Leads.Email));
```

Delete Customers from WorkBook

```
DELETE WorkBook.*, Exists (select 1 
       from Customers
WHERE WorkBook.Company Like "*" & [Customers].[Company] & "*";) AS Expr1
FROM WorkBook
WHERE (((Exists (select 1 
       from Customers
WHERE WorkBook.Company Like "*" & [Customers].[Company] & "*";))<>False));
```

Delete Competitors from WorkBook

```
DELETE WorkBook.*, Exists (select 1 
       from Competitors
WHERE WorkBook.Company Like "*" & [Competitors].[Company] & "*";) AS Expr1
FROM WorkBook
WHERE (((Exists (select 1 
       from Competitors
WHERE WorkBook.Company Like "*" & [Competitors].[Company] & "*";))<>False));
```

Any assistance on how to combine, create a union of or rewrite these queries into a single item would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what version of Microsoft Access you're using, but this should be applicable.

Had you considered running these three queries within a `transaction`?  These could be executed from a subroutine in a VBA module, and the subroutine could be executed from a button on a form or a macro.

You can find information on the Transaction statement here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950(v=office.12).aspx